# cumulative sum of NF-i fields

Tags: awk

I have

```
NC_042565.1  1   1  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  8  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
NC_042565.1  2   2  0  0  3  2  0  1  0  0  0  0  7  1  2  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
NC_042565.1  3   2  0  0  3  3  0  1  0  0  0  0  7  1  1  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
NC_042565.1  4   2  0  0  3  3  0  1  0  0  0  0  7  1  1  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
NC_042565.1  5   3  0  0  3  3  0  1  0  0  0  0  7  1  0  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

...

I would like to sum cols 14 to the last, then 15 to the last, then 16 to the last and so on.
So that I have

```
NC_042565.1  1   1  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  11  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
NC_042565.1  2   2  0  0  3  2  0  1  0  0  0  0  11  4  3  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
NC_042565.1  3   2  0  0  3  3  0  1  0  0  0  0  11  4  3  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
NC_042565.1  4   2  0  0  3  3  0  1  0  0  0  0  11  4  3  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
NC_042565.1  5   3  0  0  3  3  0  1  0  0  0  0  11  4  3  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

I tried

```
awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){$i=$i+$(i-1)}} 1'  file
```

[Calculate cumulative sum of fields within each line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51081376/calculate-cumulative-sum-of-fields-within-each-line)

and

```
awk '{for(i=15;i<=NF;i++){$i+=(s+=$NF>$i)}}1' file
```

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts. 2 questions here: 1st- sum should be saved in same column numbers of new columns should be created? 2nd- if sum is getting saved(over-written) in same column number then your desired output doesn't show it, please clarify more on it.

Comment: Hello! I would prefer to overwrite fields, but also ok if appending new columns. Thank you!

Comment: Ok sure, one more question. So 12 to last, 13 to last in your question means: 12 to 1st field and 13 to 1st field sum?

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake. I corrected the question. 15 to last, 16 to last, 17 to last, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite easy:

```
$ awk '{for(i=NF-1;i>=14;i--)$i+=$(i+1);print}' file
NC_042565.1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 11 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
NC_042565.1 2 2 0 0 3 2 0 1 0 0 0 0 11 4 3 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
NC_042565.1 3 2 0 0 3 3 0 1 0 0 0 0 11 4 3 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
NC_042565.1 4 2 0 0 3 3 0 1 0 0 0 0 11 4 3 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
NC_042565.1 5 3 0 0 3 3 0 1 0 0 0 0 11 4 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Explanation: we just process fields (`$i`) in reverse order from `$(NF-1)` down to `$14`. We modify `$i` on the fly by adding the next field (`$i+=$(i+1)`). As we proceed in reverse order `$(i+1)` is already the sum of the `$(i+1)` to `$NF` original fields. So, when adding `$(i+1)` to `$i`, `$i` becomes itself the sum of the `$i` to `$NF` original fields.

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```sh
$ awk '{
    for (n = 1; n < 15; n++) printf "%s ", $n
    sum = 0
    for (n = 15; n <= NF; n++) sum += $n
    for (n = 15; n < NF; n++) {
      printf "%d ", sum
      sum -= $n
    }
    printf "%d\n", sum
  }' input.txt
NC_042565.1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 8 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
NC_042565.1 2 2 0 0 3 2 0 1 0 0 0 0 7 4 3 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
NC_042565.1 3 2 0 0 3 3 0 1 0 0 0 0 7 4 3 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
NC_042565.1 4 2 0 0 3 3 0 1 0 0 0 0 7 4 3 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
NC_042565.1 5 3 0 0 3 3 0 1 0 0 0 0 7 4 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The trick here is to sum up all the columns once, and then loop again, subtracting the current column from that sum each time, instead of summing up all remaining columns for each column. Makes it O(N) instead of O(N²).

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` program.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  for(i=14;i<=NF;i++){
    arr[FNR,i]=$i
    sum[FNR]+=$i
  }
  next
}
{
  for(i=14;i<=NF;i++){
    diff=0
    if(i>14){
      for(j=14;j<i;j++){
        diff+=arr[FNR,j]
      }
    }
    $i=(sum[FNR]-diff)
   }
}
1
' Input_file Input_file 

NC_042565.1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 11 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
NC_042565.1 2 2 0 0 3 2 0 1 0 0 0 0 11 4 3 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
NC_042565.1 3 2 0 0 3 3 0 1 0 0 0 0 11 4 3 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
NC_042565.1 4 2 0 0 3 3 0 1 0 0 0 0 11 4 3 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
NC_042565.1 5 3 0 0 3 3 0 1 0 0 0 0 11 4 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                        ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                     ##Checking condition if FNR==NR then do following.
  for(i=14;i<=NF;i++){       ##Running for loop from 14th field to last field of line.
    arr[FNR,i]=$i            ##Creating arr with index of FNR and i with value of current field.
    sum[FNR]+=$i             ##Creating sum with index of FNR and keep adding all fields value to it.
  }
  next                       ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  for(i=14;i<=NF;i++){       ##Running for loop from 14th field to till last field here.
    diff=0                   ##Setting diff to 0 here.
    if(i>14){                ##Checking condition if i>14 then do following.
      for(j=14;j<i;j++){     ##Running for loop from 14 to till j<i here.
        diff+=arr[FNR,j]     ##Creating diff and keep adding each field value which we want to subtract to total sum.
      }
    }
    $i=(sum[FNR]-diff)       ##Setting current field value to sum[FNR](total sum) - diff here.
   }
}
1                            ##Printing current line.
' file1 file1                ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```